# Create new binary column conditioned on matching text

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I have data frame `dftxt_house` with one column `url_text` and 388 rows. I want to make a new column `blocked` conditional on the text in `url_text`. Rows in the new column `blocked` should take value `1` if the corresponding text in `url_text` contain either `blocked you` or `You're blocked` and if not value `0`. The code below works for either `blocked you` or `You're blocked` but when adding both to the code using the  `or` statement it results in value `1` on all rows in the column `blocked`.

Am I misunderstanding the `or` statement?

A look at data frame `dftxt_house`

```
dftxt_house.head()
                                                                                                                                                                                                  url_text
0  Text SIGN LIKUOL to 50409 to send this to your officials\nen)\n1 signer. Let's get to 10!\n\nAN OPEN LETTER to THE U.S. CONGRESS STARTED by JOANNE\n\nMail in Ballot being blocked by Trump\n\nHello...
1           \n\nf;\n\nMark DeSaulnier @\n\n@RepDeSaulnier\n\n@RepDeSaulnier blocked\nyou\nb ColUir- |= 0) (eel, ¢-10 macelaamiell(e\uiiate|\n\n@RepDeSaulnier and viewing\n@RepDeSaulnier’s Tweets.\n\n \n
2  JACKIE SPEIER COMMITTEE OW ARMED SERVICES\ntate Distarcr, CAuiroania SUBCOMMITTEES\n\n2465 Ravaurn House Orrice BuLOmG CHAIRWOMAN, MILiTafy PEAS INHEL\n\nWasumiaton, DC 20515-0514 , StRateaic Fonc...
3  PANGRESSMAN ERIC SWALWELL\n\nPRC <€—  VING CALIFORNIA'S 15TH CONGRESSIONAL DISTRICT\n\n \n\nFollow\n\nRep. Eric Swalwell |\n@RepSwalwell\n\n@RepSwalwell\nblocked you\nYou are blocked from followin...
```

Code that should create new binray column

```
# match all rows with the string "blocked you" or "You're blocked". 
# a user who have been blocked by another user i.e. a politician. Create new column with 0 = no block and 1 = block
dftxt_house['blocked'] = dftxt_house.apply(
    lambda row: 1 if 'blocked you' or "You're blocked" in row['url_text'] else 0,
    axis=1
)
```

Current "wrong" result

```
dftxt_house['blocked'].value_counts()
1    388
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are indeed misunderstanding the `or` statement, it should look like this

```
dftxt_house['blocked'] = dftxt_house.apply(
    lambda row: 1 if 'blocked you' in row['url_text'] or "You're blocked" in row['url_text'] else 0,
    axis=1
```